# Simple Typed Racket program doesn't type-check

Tags: scheme, racket, typechecking, typed-racket

I'm a rank beginner with Typed Racket, and I was playing around with the very simple `Tree` type defined in the [Beginner's Guide](http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/current/doc/ts-guide/beginning.html):

```
#lang typed/racket
(define-type Tree (U leaf node))
(struct: leaf ([val : Number]))
(struct: node ([left : Tree] [right : Tree]))
```

As an exercise, I decided to write a higher-order function to descend the tree:

```
(: tree-descend : All (A) (Number -> A) (A A -> A) Tree -> A)
(define (tree-descend do-leaf do-node tree)
  (if (leaf? tree)
      (do-leaf (leaf-val tree))
      (do-node (tree-descend do-leaf do-node (node-left tree))
               (tree-descend do-leaf do-node (node-right tree)))))
```

This type-checks fine. However, when I try to use it to redefine the `tree-sum` function that sums all over the leaves, I get a surprising and verbose error message:

```
(: tree-sum : Tree -> Number)
(define (tree-sum t)
  (tree-descend identity + t))
```

The error messages are

> ```
> Type Checker: Polymorphic function `tree-descend' could not be applied to arguments:
>   Argument 1:
>     Expected: (Number -> A)
>     Given:    (All (a) (a -> a))
>   Argument 2:
>     Expected: (A A -> A)
>     Given:    (case-> (-> Zero) (Zero Zero -> Zero) (One Zero -> One) 
>                (Zero One -> One) (Positive-Byte Zero -> Positive-Byte)  
>                [...lots of ways of combining subtypes of Number...]
>                (Index Positive-Index Index -> Positive-Fixnum) 
>                (Index Index Positive-Index -> in: (tree-descend identity + t)
> ```

Now, to my untrained eye, it looks like this should work just fine, because clearly the polymorphic type `A` should just be `Number` and then everything works. Obviously the language disagrees with me for some reason, but I'm not sure what that reason is.

Comment: You seem to have an extra argument in type for `tree-sum` which I think you left in from some earlier version of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Typed Racket can't infer the proper instantiation of polymorphic functions like `tree-descend` when you apply them to polymorphic arguments like `identity`. If you replace `identity` with `(inst identity Number)`, then the program works fine.